# How to solve T(n) = T(n-1) + n^2?

Tags: recurrence-relation

See title. I'm trying to apply the method from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674719/easy-solve-tn-tn-1n-by-iteration-method). What I have so far is this, but I don't know how to proceed from here on:

T(n) = T(n-1) + n2

T(n-1) = T(n-2) + (n-1)2 = T(n-2) + n2 - 2n + 1

T(n-2) = T(n-3) + (n-2)2 = T(n-3) + n2 - 4n + 4

T(n-3) = T(n-4) + (n-3)2 = T(n-4) + n2 - 6n + 9

Substituting the values of T(n-1), T(n-2) and T(n-3) into T(n) gives:

T(n) = T(n-2) + 2n2 - 2n + 1

T(n) = T(n-3) + 3n2 - 6n + 5

T(n) = T(n-4) + 4n2 - 12n + 14

Now I have to find a pattern but I don't really know how to do that. What I got is:

T(n) = T(n-k) + kn2 - ...???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solving or approximating recurrence relations for sequences of numbers](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers)

Comment: @D.W. Since the OP did actually try and do something (and Rick's answer is outstanding), I think we can keep this one.

Comment: Suggested to use Tex formatting for mathematical formulae.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't expand the squared terms; it'll just add confusion. Think of the recurrence as
$$
T(\fbox{foo}) = T(\fbox{foo}-1)+\fbox{foo}\;^2
$$
where you can replace *foo* with anything you like. Then from
$$
T(n)=T(n-1)+n^2
$$
you can replace $T(n-1)$ by $T(n-2)+(n-1)^2$ by putting $n-1$ in the boxes above, yielding
$$
T(n) = [T(n-2) + (n-1)^2]+n^2 = T(n-2)+(n-1)^2+n^2
$$
and similarly
$$\begin{align}
T(n) &= T(n-2)+(n-1)^2+n^2\\
     &= T(n-3)+(n-2)^2+(n-1)^2+n^2\\
     &= T(n-4)+(n-3)^2+(n-2)^2+(n-1)^2+n^2
\end{align}$$
and in general you'll have
$$
T(n) = T(n-k)+(n-k+1)^2+(n-k+2)^2+\dotsm+(n-1)^2+n^2
$$
Now if we let $k=n$ we'll have
$$
T(n) = T(0)+1^2+2^2+3^2+\dotsm+n^2
$$
Now if you just need an upper bound for $T(n)$ observe that
$$
1^2+2^2+3^2+\dotsm+n^2\le \underbrace{n^2+n^2+n^2+\dotsm+n^2}_n=n^3
$$
so we conclude that $T(n)=O(n^3)$, in asymptotic notation.

For a more exact estimate, you can look up the equation for the [sum of squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number):
$$
1^2+2^2+\dotsm+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$$
so
$$
T(n)=T(0)+\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$$

Comment: Really clear explanation, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Just start with:

$\begin{align}
  T(k) - T(k - 1)
    &= k^2 \\
  \sum_{1 \le k \le n} (T(k) - T(k - 1))
    &= \sum_{1 \le k \le n} k^2 \\
  T(n) - T(0)
    &= \frac{n (n + 1) (2 n + 1)}{6}
\end{align}$

by telescoping (see also [square piramidal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number)).